# HttpModule disables SharePoint 2003 admin

Tags: c#, httpmodule, sharepoint-2003

I have a web part with links to e.g. "Manage Users" i SharePoint (2003)

I also have a http module, that must add some JavaScript to the aspx pages served through the sharePoint site. This runs well for normal user served pages but when clicking these admin pages, served by the web part...

What can be wrong and how do I adapt my filter to allow these pages being served with script?

The Http Module is working with this event: ReleaseRequestState...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was wrong was that the filter must be enabled for the virtual  directory in the 60 hive. The pages failing was all from the /_layouts/ folder.

That is you have to update the web.config in the LAYOUTS folder and add the dll + any referenced dll's to the corresponding bin folder.